# Add some diversity to the Recent Badges list

Tags: feature-request, badges, homepage

In every site's homepage there is the Recent Badges list to the right. It's good and help people learn about the existence of badges and as a result encourage them to do good things.

However, as it stands only a few selected badges are ever shown there due to being the common badges: "[something] Question", "[something] Answer" and sometimes Enlightened or Necromancer. But what about the others? For example it would be great to see [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist) there so people will get to know it.

I suggest to add some logic to that list instead of taking the "dry" 32 most recently awarded.

1. From the pool of 84 (non tag) badges randomly select 32.
2. Show the most recent award for each of those badges.

This will add diversity to the list, "featuring" different badges every time and in my opinion will encourage more users to get those badges they never saw before.

Comment: I'd rather remove that list entirely, it doesn't serve any useful purpose in my opinion and just clutters up the sidebar.

Comment: I'm raising my fist in the air, shouting "C# Power!" right now.

Comment: @Mad I disagree. It's useful statistics, most users have no clue about badges so seeing this they might get to learn about them.

Comment: I don't know if I've ever scrolled down far enough on the homepage to realize those were there...

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ shame on you! :-D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "Badges" is one of the top-level navigation items, and users get notifications for their badges when they earn them. I think that badges have sufficient visibility.